# MariaDB remote access

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mariadb

I am using `laravel 5.4` and on remote server `ubuntu 16.04` with latest mariaDB,

I made almost all the configuration listed in google and also i revert to the original state.

My current problem is that i cannot connect to my remote `mariadb`. Credentials are absolutely fine.

I changed the `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf` file for the `bind-address` where i gave the ip of the server, The ip where i can access my `phpmyadmin` like `1.1.1.1/phpmyadmin`. Current `.env` setting is :

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=1.1.1.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=*******
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=********
```

But the error it throws `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`.

Comment: Did you check your firewall configuration on the MariaDB server? Port 3306 should be open. Also change bind-address to 0.0.0.0 so it will listen on all IP addresses. Don't forget to restart the MariaDB service to activate the changes.

Comment: @ThomasSnijder Things you have mentioned are all reviewed. Ports are open, And i tried bind-address 0.0.0.0, Still not working

Comment: Did you create a account on the MariaDB server that allows root to connect from the given IP address? normally a account is created like this: grant all on laravel.* to root@localhost identified by '<password>'; When using this root can only connect from the localhost.

Comment: Yes i have created the account too.

Comment: And also gave the permissions.

Comment: The error message implies that there is a firewall issues or that the service is not running. So you should check that again and make sure that any device in between accepts the connection on port 3306. Otherwise I don't know either.

Comment: What do you get with `telnet 1.1.1.1 3306`?  (If mysqld is running on 1.1.1.1)

Answer (score 0):

Check your AppArmor profiles.  It may be blocking the mysqld process from accessing network.

`$ sudo apparmor_status`

Make sure mysqld is not in any "enforce" mode.

Check to see if there is a mysqld profile in /etc/apparmor.d/

`$ ls /etc/apparmor.d/*mysqld*`

To disable it, put a simlink in /etc/apparmor.d/disable/

`$ sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/<full_name_of_mysqld_file> /etc/apparmor.d/disable/`

followed by

`$ sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/<full_name_of_mysqld_file>`

Verify that mysqld protection is disabled:

`$ sudo aa-status`